# how to filter array items in js without filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

here is the question

- Filter out companies which have more than one 'o' without the filter method
- 0: "Facebook"
  1: "Google"
  2: "Microsoft"
  3: "Apple"
  4: "IBM"
  5: "Oracle"
  6: "Amazon"

Comment: please add your specific problem with this taks. please add your code.

Comment: You can't. Whatever method you'll create for this, will become a filter method.

Comment: Why you don't want to use filter method? This is one of the most efficient way to do what you are looking for.

Comment: @Bloodbee It's a homework, and those often contains artificial limitations to force students really learn the basics.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: actually its not a homework im following a repo to learn js and thats the all details given by the author so nothing to do sorry if i made mistake thats my first question although using stackoverflow more than a year :D

Comment: The issues are the same regardless if it is actually homework or not

Comment: @KeremUYSAL Well, the question being actually a homework or a course task etc. doesn't matter, it's categorically a "homework question". Please read the help article charlietfl has linked, and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array and check if each word has more than one "o".

Here is a function to verify the word:

```js
const verif=(word)=>{
  var s=0
  var l=word.length

  for(let i=0 ; i<=l;i++) {
    if (word[i]=="o") {
      s++
    }
  }
  if (s>=2) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon' ]

let OCompanies = []; // declare an empty array for 'O' letter companies
    
// use for loop to loop through itCompanies array 
for (let index = 0; index < itCompanies.length; index++) {
// get individual element of the array
const company = itCompanies[index];
// using split method, you can split the string based on the delimeter 'o'. you can then use length method of the array to determine the number of occurances 
const count = company.split('o').length - 1;
// check if the company contains more than one 'o'
if (count > 1) {
  // use push method to add elements to the OCompanies array
  OCompanies.push(company)
}
}

console.log(OCompanies) // ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:-

```js
const itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon']
const zeroContaineCompany = []
for(let i=0; i<itCompanies.length; i++){
    if(itCompanies[i].includes('o')){
        const zeroCount = itCompanies[i].toLowerCase().split('');
        let count = 0
        for(let j=0; j< zeroCount.length; j++){
            if( zeroCount[j] === 'o'){
                count += 1
            }
        }
        if(count>1){
            zeroContaineCompany.push(itCompanies[i])
        }
    }
}
console.log(zeroContaineCompany)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I consider your array as:

```
var itCompanies = ['Facebook','Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM' , 'Oracle', 'Amazon']
```

Declare an empty array where you will have final results:

```
var finalCompanies=[]
```

Loop through all the elements of given array then, assign the current item of array to a new string inside the loop. Use the string.match() function store all returned 'o' in a new array. check if the new array is null or not (because some string may have no "o"). Now, if new array is not null, and value of length of that array is greater or equal to 2. push the current company string in results array:

```
for(let i=0; i<= itCompanies.length - 1; i++){
var checkingCompany = itCompanies[i] //
var currentCompArr = checkingCompany.match(/o/g)
   if (currentCompArr != null){
   if(currentCompArr.length>=2){
    finalCompanies.push(checkingCompany)
  }
 }
}
```

Now, run a loop to print all the elements stored in the results array:

```
for(let y=0; y<=finalCompanies.length-1; y++){
console.log(finalCompanies[y])
}
```

To sum up, your final code will look like:

```js
var itCompanies = ['Facebook','Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM' , 'Oracle', 'Amazon']
var finalCompanies=[]
for(let i=0; i<= itCompanies.length - 1; i++){
    var checkingCompany = itCompanies[i] //
    var currentCompArr = checkingCompany.match(/o/g)
       if (currentCompArr != null){
       if(currentCompArr.length>=2){
        finalCompanies.push(checkingCompany)
       }
    }
}
for(let y=0; y<=finalCompanies.length-1; y++){
    console.log(finalCompanies[y])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function a iterate through each array element

```
    function filterArray(arr, fn) {

    let filteredArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (fn(arr[i]) === true) {
            filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
        } 
    }
    return filteredArray;
}

function isIsogram (str) {
    return !/(.).*\1/.test(str);
}

const arr = ["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle", "Amazon"];
console.log(filterArray(arr, isIsogram));
```